# VBA - Uploading a file to sharepoint document library stopped working

Tags: vba, sharepoint

Our SharePoint site used to be on-prem, and it migrated to the one hosted on the cloud.
We had the following VBA code to upload a file to its document library, and it stopped working although we have the correct new URL. It doesn't throw any error, but it just doesn't upload the file. Is there another way do upload a file? Thank you very much.

```
' To read source files as byte
Dim binaryByte() As Byte
Dim binaryByteData As Variant

'Get lngFileLength for binarybyte initialization.
Dim lngFileLength As Long

'Initilizate the scripting object for getting folder information.
Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

' Initialize the xmlhttp object
Dim LobjXML As Object
Set LobjXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

'Set sharepoint URL from tbl_Lookup
sSharePointURL = ELookup("SharePointFolderURLPath", "tbl_Lookup")

'Get path of file to publish
sFilePath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Published"

' Get the filename
sFileNameWithPath = sFilePath & "\" & ELookup("FrontEndFileNameAccdb", "tbl_Lookup")

'Array length identification
lngFileLength = FileLen(sFileNameWithPath) - 1

'Reinitialize the byte array
ReDim binaryByte(lngFileLength)

'Open file binary consumption
Open sFileNameWithPath For Binary As #1
Get #1, , binaryByte
Close #1

' Convert to variant to upload.
binaryByteData = binaryByte

'Destination URL
sDestinationURL = sSharePointURL & ELookup("FrontEndFileNameAccdb", "tbl_Lookup")

' Upload the data to the server, false means synchronous.
LobjXML.Open "PUT", sDestinationURL, False

    

  Set LobjXML = Nothing
  Set objFSO = Nothing
```

Comment: i'm not sure about using VBA, but MS `powerapps` or `typescript` would be good for this.

Comment: @pgSystemTester - thank you, but it has to be VBA

Comment: You might be looking at authentication issues. I would map the SharePoint location as a local drive letter. Then it can be accessed as if it were local.

Comment: Try [SynchronizeWSSandExcel Addin](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/05/synchronize-between-sharepoint-list-and-excel.html)